# How to add a variable to columns headers in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say I have the following df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'$a':[1,2], '$b': [10,20],'$A':[1,2], '$B': [10,20]})
```

and I would need to concatenate the headers with a variable
lets say i have:

```
headers = ['NY', 'TA']
```

and I would like to do something like

```
for h in headers:
    df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.rename(h + x), inplace=True)
```

I know that `x.rename(h + x)` is wrong. pls advice how to get:

```
    NY $A   NY $B   NY $a   NY $b   TA $A   TA $B   TA $a   TA $b
0   1        10       1     10      1       10      1       10
1   2        20       2     20      2       20      2       20
```

here is the full loop

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pandas as pd

start = datetime(2010, 1, 1)
end = pd.datetime.now()
datasets_original_test = ['AAPL', 'MSFT']

for d in datasets_original_test:
    data_original = web.DataReader(d, 'yahoo', start, end)
    #THIS IS MY PROBLEM##########################
    data_original.rename(columns=lambda x: x.concate(d, x), inplace=True)
    #THIS IS MY PROBLEM##########################
    datasets_test.append(data_original)

df_returns = pd.concat(datasets_test, axis=1, join_axes=[datasets_test[0].index])
```

Comment: I don't think you can just use rename, because your dataframe needs to "grow" in columns to match your naming convention.  So, you need to concatenate duplicates or something get the additional columns in your dataframe.

Comment: I just edited for a better explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a litte bit more a dynamic way:

```
df_out = pd.concat([df]*len(headers), axis=1, keys=headers)
```

Or use @Wen-Ben's shortcut:

```
df_out = pd.concat(dict.fromkeys(headers,df),1)

df_out.columns = df_out.columns.map(' '.join)
df_out
```

Output:

```
   NY $a  NY $b  NY $A  NY $B  TA $a  TA $b  TA $A  TA $B
0      1     10      1     10      1     10      1     10
1      2     20      2     20      2     20      2     20
```

Comment: `df_out = pd.concat(dict.fromkeys(headers,df),1)` :-)

Comment: Wow... that's a new one for me... Thanks @Wen-Ben.

Comment: this created another header above current headers. nice

Comment: You can use the map line to join the two level headers into one get your expected output.

Comment: what is the map line?

Comment: `df_out.columns = df_out.columns.map(' '.join)`  That flattens the multiindex columns in to a single level column header.

Answer (score 2):

You can use add_prefix

```
pd.concat([df.add_prefix(h) for h in headers], axis = 1, sort = False)

    NY$a    NY$b    NY$A    NY$B    TA$a    TA$b    TA$A    TA$B
0   1       10      1       10      1       10      1       10
1   2       20      2       20      2       20      2       20
```

If you want space, use

```
pd.concat([df.add_prefix(h + ' ') for h in headers], axis = 1, sort = False)
```

Comment: Nice generalization of @MeW solution. +1